# View that moves along with keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview, ios7, autolayout

I have an iOS app with a `UIScrollView` that basically looks like the Messages.app: content on the screen and on the bottom a text view and a button to add more content. When the keyboard appears the text view and button move up correctly.

I've set `keyboardDismissMode` so that dragging the keyboard down makes it disappear but during the process of the dragging, as the keyboard is moving down, how can I update my views' locations on screen to stay attached to it? It seems that the keyboard will change frame notification isn't fired during this process.

What's the "right" way of doing this?

**Edit**: I have a hunch it might be doable using an input view/accessory view, but not sure that's the right direction to go.

Comment: sorry thought you wanted to change the keyboard position. If you want to observe it, I updated my answer to show how you can do it with KVO as suggested by others.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem??

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure this behavior requires SPI. BUT: You could walk the view/window hierarchy, find the keyboard window, and apply a transform to it to move it during your interaction. (*window.transform=*)

Not sure what to do when your interaction ends however--maybe manually animate the keyboard away (using the above technique) to finish the keyboard hide, then when it's hidden, resign first responder without animating.

EDIT:

Sorry, I thought you wanted to move the keyboard, but if you want to observe the keyboards position, you can use KVO for that (as @KudoCC suggested)

```
static void * __keyboardCenterKVOContext = & __keyboardCenterKVOContext ;

-(void)setUpKeyboardObserver
{
    UIView * keyboardView = ...?
    [ keyboardView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"center" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionInitial context:__keyboardCenterKVOContext ] ;
}
```

Then implement the KVO observer:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    if ( context == __keyboardCenterKVOContext )
    {
        CGPoint newKeyboardCenter = [ [ change valueForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey ] pointValue ] ;
        // .. handle new keyboard position here ...
    }
    else
    {
        [ super observeValueForKeyPath:keyPath ofObject:object change:change context:context ] ;
    }
}
```

Your KVO observer will be run every time the keyboard view changes it's center property. You might also try observing the keyboard window's `frame` and/or `transform` properties.

I have some code to help with KVO observing here, which might help you: https://gist.github.com/nielsbot/6873377

(The reason you might want to use my helper code is because it automatically removes KVO observation from objects that are being deallocated. This requires some run time fiddling, but in your case you don't really know when the keyboard window will be deallocated. Although maybe you can tear down KVO in your keyboardWillHide handler)

Comment: I don't know what SPI means :) And would love to hear of a "cleaner" solution

Comment: I don't know SPI too, do you mean system private interface ?

Comment: SPI = system programming interface. I.e. private APIs that will get your application rejected from the App Store if you use them. also your app may just stop working in a future OS because SPI is not guaranteed to not change without notice

Comment: Hmmmm, that might work, if there's a way to get the keyboard view

Comment: there's probably a way that's not _too_ hacky. For example, you could create an accessory keyboard view that's 0x0, override it's `-didMoveToSuperview` and see what window you land in.

Answer (score 0):

You can try notification to move your content when keyboard disappear and appear:

```
    NSNotificationCenter *center = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardDisappeared) name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
    [center addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardAppeared) name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];


    -(void) keyboardDisappeared
    {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:yourAnimationOption  animations:^
            {
                   self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y+100(same as you do in keyboardAppeared), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

            } completion::^(BOOL finished) 
                 {
               }];
    }

 -(void) keyboardAppeared
    {
     [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 delay:0 options:yourAnimationOption  animations:^
            {
                   self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y-(as much you want), self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);

            } completion::^(BOOL finished) 
                 {
               }];
    }
```

Comment: That's the whole problem, those events are not triggered while the `keyboardDismissMode` drag is happening